# Frames generated in rendering and painting an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, qtwebkit

How do I get the timings and layouts of different frames generated while painting an HTML page which involves javascript manipulations and CSS3 animations by a webkit browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the page layout by `dumpRenderTree()` provided by webkit, if that's what you wanted. Regarding the timing data, as far as I know you may need to build the webkit engine to enable it then you can get the timing data regarding rendering, network, Javascript, etc. - at least this is feasible for Android webkit.

Comment: Hi Wang, this is the page layout, rather what i expect is each and every frame generated during an animation and if there was a skip in frame generation.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to find some helper functions in the webkit engine to **ONLY** dump one particular frame... And if you're interested in the time cost of CSS animation and JS execution you may need to build your own webkit engine, modifying a couple lines of code maybe.